# Print data from axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I try to print data from axios.

In controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return User::latest(); 
}
```

In `user.vue`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadUsers() {
      axios.get('/user').then(({ data }) => (this.users = user))
      console.log(user)
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadUsers()
  },
}
```

And table:

```html
<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Web

```
Route::get('/user','UserController@index');
```

`console.log` prints the data, but in table no data.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. What does dd(User::latest()) give you?

Comment: i guess should be: `.then(({ data }) => (this.users = data))`

Answer (score 0):

axios call async call so make a promise call `.then()` after fetching data it will call and you can make usable the fetched data.

```js
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = "http://192.168.1.26:8000";

export class BaseStatus_Service {
    getBaseStatus_list() {
        const url = `${API_URL}/api/baf1/baseStatus`;
        return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data);
    }

const serviceUtil = new BaseStatus_Service();
serviceUtil.getBaseStatus_list().then((results)=>{
      console.log(results);
})
```